# React Js : Passing a condition to a state value based on another state value

Tags: java, reactjs, web, state

I have been scattering the internet in search of an answer but my guess is that what i am doing is either wrong or i don't know the right therm because i can't find any relevant answer. Long story short, i want to pass a condition to a state value that is based on another state value inside the constructor. Why? Because i am building a "Form Generator" and i want to be able to link an input to another one. Exemple : If a checked box is checked, then you can enter text inside a text input otherwise it is disabled. Pretty simple right? If anybody can just point me in a direction that would be great. So far this is what i have tried but it doesn't work.

```
constructor(props){

this.state = 
Inputs : [
  //Theres a bunch of inputs here
  {
     name : "Icon",
     group: 1,
     width: 6,
     type: "select",
     label: "Icon du menu",
     disabled: () =>(
          !this.state.Inputs[0].value //I want to link the disable property to an
                                      //input value
     ),
      value: "" 
   }
]
}
```

I have also tried to create a constraint object in my state and iterate trough the value during the mounting process but i found it to be too fragile and time consuming. If i could directly create the link inside the input object that would be great.

Thanks for your time and great wisdom!
-Sam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want the initial index [0] to have a different disabled function than `!this.state.Inputs[0].value` or else the disabled property of all inputs will be stuck and never change.

Here is a demonstration on how to link the `disabled` property to the `input` value of another:

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      inputs: [
        {
          name : "Form1",
          disabled: () => { return false; },
          value: "" 
        },
        {
          name : "Form2",
          disabled: () => { return this.state.inputs[0].value === ""; },
          value: "" 
        },
        {
          name : "Form3",
          disabled: () => { return this.state.inputs[0].value === ""; },
          value: "" 
        }
      ]
    };
  }
  
  onInputChange = (e, index) => {
    const newInputs = this.state.inputs;
    newInputs[index].value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ inputs: newInputs });
  };
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.inputs && 
            this.state.inputs.map((inputItem, index) => {
                return (
                  <div>
                    {this.state.inputs[index].name}:
                    <input onChange={(e) => { this.onInputChange(e, index); }} disabled={this.state.inputs[index].disabled()}/>
                  </div>
                );
            })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

In the demonstration if you have a value, other than an empty string, for the first input, it will unlock the rest of the inputs for user input.